# row-wise correlation in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, correlation

I have 2 tensors. i.e

```
tensor_1 = tf.constant([[1, 2, 1],
                        [3, 4, 3],
                        [5, 6, 5]], dtype=tf.float16)
tensor_2 = tf.constant([[-1, -2, -1], 
                        [6, 8, 6], 
                        [-5, -6, -5]], dtype = tf.float16)
```

I want to compute the row wise correlation of the tensors. Hence, the desired output is a tensor with `[-1,1,-1]` in it.

I tried to use `tf.map_fn`. However, I do not get how to use it with an input of two tensors as I have it.

Further I tried, `tfp.stats.correlation(tensor_1, tensor_2, 0, 1)`. But this returns the matrix with the wanted correlation coefficients in the **diagonal**. But I think there must be a more efficient way of computing the row-wise correlations.

**Libraries**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
```